# I need make a Form the custom module

Tags: templates, module, forms

In first, sorry to something.
I'm new in EE and need make a form of custom table.

ex: 
my table have 4 fields, name, old, address, city. (this is only example.)
and need make in control panel a form to cadastre, edit, delete my register.

I looked in many sites and only saw about EE 1 but I'm using EE 2.8.

can somebody tell me any site or examples to I follow and study more?

one more time, sorry something.

Comment: I think you may need to try and explain what you are doing a little more. I appreciate that English isn't your first language but it's quite difficult to know what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry my English. So, I have a module with some fields. end I need create all control panel, create, update and delete objects this module. I need list objects and form for create and updade objects.

you know ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Development Documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html) for a broad overview of topics that will be relevant to building your module.

Specifically though, you will want to drill into the [module development instructions](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html) and go through the [module development tutorial](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html) that comes with [sample code](https://github.com/EllisLab/ee-tuts-download-module) that you can learn from.